# connect to raspberry pi with socketio

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp, raspberry-pi

I want to connect to a Raspberry with the server and client example scripts from the [socketio documentation](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html).
Im using the first client and server example code.

When I run the server script on the pi, I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ python3 server_socketio.py
(792) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:5000
```

so this seems to be working.

When I run the client script on my Ubuntu 20.04 PC, I get:

```
/usr/bin/python3.8 /home/marco/Schreibtisch/BlinkingLED/client_socketio.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marco/Schreibtisch/BlinkingLED/client_socketio.py", line 29, in <module>
    sio.connect('http://0.0.0.0:5000')
  File "/home/marco/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/socketio/client.py", line 314, in connect
    raise exceptions.ConnectionError(exc.args[0]) from None
socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection refused by the server
```

I tried to open the port on the pi with

```
sudo apt-get install ufw
sudo ufw allow 5000
sudo ufw enable
sudo reboot
```

which gives

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
5000                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8090                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8090 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

whereas netstat gives:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      471/vncserver-x11-c 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      480/sshd            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      419/cupsd           
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN      471/vncserver-x11-c 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      480/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      419/cupsd
```

Changing the port inside the python scripts too 5900 or 8090 does also not work. What is wrong? Is there a better war to open a port on the raspberry pi? As I understand it ufw is a firewall. I had to <sudo ufw allow 22> before I was able to connect to my pi via ssh again.
Pleas help.

Comment: You can find the address you need to use by running `hostname -I` on your RasPi.

Answer (score 0):

The server listens on `0.0.0.0:5000`. The special IP address `0.0.0.0` ("any address") in this context means to listen for incoming connections on all local interfaces (loopback, ethernet, etc.). And `5000` is the port number, no problem with that.

The client tries to connect to `0.0.0.0:5000`. The special IP address `0.0.0.0` as destination address is invalid. The computer does not know where to send networks packets to. "Any address" is unusable here, you have to provide a real IP address that is reachable over the network which connects the client with the server.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works when  I use my local IP address in the client.py on my PC as address for the connect function: 192.168.2.112. But whe I go to some homepage which gives me my public IP and then use this in the client.py, it does not work anymore. Can you please tell me why that is so? My PC and my raspberrypi are connected to the same router, could that be some issue?

Comment: @M.Hoppe All addresses starting with `192.168.` are for private use only and not valid on Internet. When you make a connection to the Internet, your provider will transparently translate the private address to a public IP address. Public IPv4 addresses are a scarce resource. Here is an article about this topic: https://whatismyipaddress.com/private-ip